# How do parallel multi instance loop work in Camunda 7.16.6

Tags: camunda, bpmn

I'm using the camunda-enginge 7.16.6.
I have a Process with a multi instance loop like this one that repeats parallel a 1000 times.
[image: BPMN Model with multi instance loop]

This loop is execute parallel. My assumption was, that n camunda executors now starts their work so executor #1 executes Task 2, then Task 3, then Task 4, and executor #2 and all others do the same. So after a short while at least some of the 1000 times finished all three Tasks in the loop

However what I observed so far is, that Task 2 gets execute 1000 times and only when that is finished, Task 3 gets executed a 1000 times and so on.
I also noticed, that camunda takes a lot of time by itself, outside of the tasks.

Is my Observation correct and is this behavior documented somewhere? Can you change that behavior?

Answer (score 3):

I've run some tests an can explain the behavior:
The Order of Tasks and the overall time to finish is influenced by whenever or not there are transaction boundaries (async after, the red bars in the Screenshot).
Its a bit described [here](https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/best-practices/development/understanding-transaction-handling-c7/#using-additional-save-points).

> By setting the asyncBefore='true' attribute we introduce an additional save point at which the process state will be persisted and committed to the database. **A separate job executor thread** will continue the process asynchronously by using a separate database transaction. In case this transaction fails the service task will be retried and eventually marked as failed - in order to be dealt with by a human operator.

**repeat 1000 times, parallel, no transaction**
[image]
One Job Executor rushes trough the process, the Order is  1, [2,3,4|2,3,4|...], 5. Not really parallel. But this is as documented [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#concurrent-job-execution):

> The Job Executor makes sure that jobs from a single process instance are never executed concurrently.

> It can be turned off if you are an expert and know what you are doing (and have understood this section).

Overall this took around 5 seconds.

**repeat 1000 times, parallel, with transaction**
[image]
Here, due the transactions, there will be 1000 waiting Jobs for Task 7, and each finish Task 7 creates another Job of Task 8. Since the execution of the Jobs is by the order in the database ([see here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#the-job-order-of-job-acquisition)), the order is 6,[7,7,7...8,8,8...9,9,9...],10.

The transaction handling which includes maintaining the variables has a huge impact on the runtime, with Transactions in parallel mode it runs 06:33 minutes.

If you turn off the `exclusive`-[flag](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#exclusive-jobs) it takes around 4:30 minutes, but at the cost of thousands of OptimisticLockingExceptions.
Afaik the recommended approach to gain true parallelism would be to move Task 7, Task 8 and Task 9 to a seperate process and spawn 1000 instances of that process.

You can influence the order of execution if you tweak the job executor settings & priority, [see here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.16/user-guide/process-engine/the-job-executor/#the-job-order-of-job-acquisition), but that seems to require the exclusive flag, too. If you do that, the Order will be 6,[7,7,7|8,9,8,9(in random order),...]10

**repeat 1000 times, sequential, no transaction**
[image]

The Order is 11,[12,13,14|12,13,14,...]15

This takes only 2 seconds.

**repeat 1000 times, sequential, with transaction**
[image]
The order is as expected 16,[17,18,19|17,18,19|...],20

Due the Transactions this takes 02:45 minutes.

I heard from colleges, that one should use parallel only if it involves long running/blocking tasks like a human task - in sequential mode there would only be one human task, and after that one is done, another will be created. in parallel mode, you have 1000 human tasks which is more likely the desired behavior.
Parallel performance seems to be [improved in Camunda 8](https://camunda.com/blog/2022/04/why-performance-of-parallel-tasks-in-camunda-platform-8-is-so-good/)